# Swift 5.2 - Dictionary with array - How to set correctly

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I want to practice with a dictionary with URL arrays, like the one below:

```
import UIKit

var urlArray:[Int:[URL]] = [:]

for section in 1..<4 {
   self.urlArray[section, default: [URL]()] = [URL]()
   for index in 1..<10 {
      let urlString = "https://picsum.photos/id/\(index)/300/150"
      if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        self.urlArray[section]?.append(url)
      }
   }
}
```

but the `urlArray`, after the for loop, as nil.
How can I correctly set the dictionary with array `[Int: [URL]]`?

Comment: `urlArray` can't be nil. It's not optional. Do you mean it's _empty_?

Comment: I cannot reproduce (even if "nil" is replaced with "empty"). Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: I couldn't find any issue. I got output, just changed self.urlArray to urlArray

Answer (score 2):

Replace `self.urlArray` with `urlArray` -- these are two different vars.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. How can I order `urlArray` by `section`?

Comment: `urlArray.sort(by: { $0.key < $1.key })`

Comment: Your solution `urlArray.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })` works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like `Yonat` suggested, I suspect the problem is that both local and instance variables exist with the name `urlArray`. The local is the one you assign a non-nil value, but you're accessing the instance variable, which is still `nil`. You could fix it by removing the local variable, and just exclusively referencing the instance variable.

I would also recommend against names like "urlArray", instead just use the plural form: `urls`, which leads to some really nice syntax like `for url in urls { ...`

More generally, I would improve this code by building up the dictionary in a more "functional" style:

```
import Foundation

let items = (1..<4).flatMap { section in
    (1..<10).map { index -> (section: Int, url: URL) in
        return (section, URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/id/\(index)/300/150")!)
    }
}

let urlsBySection: [Int: [URL]] = Dictionary(grouping: items, by: { $0.section })
    .mapValues { pairs in pairs.map { $0.url } } // strip aways the sections

// Printing the results for demonstration:
for (section, urls) in urlsBySection {
    print("Section \(section)")
    for url in urls {
        print(" - \(url)")
    }
}

/* Result:
Section 2
 - https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/2/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/3/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/4/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/5/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/6/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/7/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/8/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/9/300/150
Section 3
 - https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/2/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/3/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/4/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/5/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/6/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/7/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/8/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/9/300/150
Section 1
 - https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/2/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/3/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/4/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/5/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/6/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/7/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/8/300/150
 - https://picsum.photos/id/9/300/150
*/
```

Comment: @CesarePiersigilli Try stepping through the debugger to learn more about it works. If you have any questions, I'd be happy to answer them

Comment: How can I order `urlsBySection` by section?

Comment: It's a dictionary, and dictionaries don't have any definite ordering. You could call `Dictionary.sorted()` on it, but what would would get back is a `[(section: Int, url: URL)]` (a.k.a. `Array<(section: Int, url: URL)>`, an array of tuples). That would lose the ability to quickly look up by key, that the dictionary provides. If that ordered array of tuples is what you were looking for, you could just get that by-construction. That's what `items` already is.

Comment: Can you give me an example from your `urlsBySection` or is it not possible?

Comment: @CesarePiersigilli Well first of all: do you understand how this code works? Until you do, much of this conversation won't make much sense, so I'd rather focus on clarifying that, first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210699/discussion-between-alexander-reinstate-monica-and-cesare-piersigilli).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Thank you all.

```
import Foundation

var urlsArray : [Int:[URL]] = [:]

func rangeFor(section: Int) -> Range<Int> {
    switch section {
    case 1: return Range(100...105)
    case 2: return Range(300...306)
    case 3: return Range(400...412)
    case 4: return Range(500...505)
    case 5: return Range(600...612)
    case 6: return Range(700...710)
    case 7: return Range(800...815)
    default:
        fatalError()
    }
}

for section in 1..<8 {
    urlsArray[section] = [URL]()
    for index in rangeFor(section: section) {
        let urlString = "https://picsum.photos/id/\(index)/100/100"
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            urlsArray[section]?.append(url)
        }
    }
}

//Stampa
for (section, urls) in urlsArray {
    print("Section: \(section)")
    for url in urls {
        print("url: \(url)")
    }
}
```

I was unable to put the sections in ascending order.